# I need to loop through information from a websites source and put it into a table in php

Tags: php

Hello im trying to pull some information from a website to put it into a table, then print it in php

i'm using the DOM parser as it looks like its exactly what i need

```
 <?php

 include 'simple_html_dom.php';

 $html = file_get_html('http://evolve.sg-community.de/index.php?page=plugins');
 $table = $html->find('#theTable');

 $theData = array();

 foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td.text') as $cell) {
       $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
    }
    $theData[] = $rowData;
 }
 print_r($theData);
 ?>
```

i keep getting

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

at

```
 foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
```

Comment: I don't see any code written by you. I am not a moderator here, but my suggestion for you is that, you first try to write some code on your own and then post questions here if you have any problem in that. How to's are not something you should be asking here at SO

Comment: I've just reformatted your code, hopefully a kindly reviewer will approve that shortly! People will be more likely to help you if your code is easy to read, so they can get directly to solving the problem, rather than struggling to find the relevant part. As for the fatal error, $table is not an object - which means that $html->find('#theTable') isn't finding anything. What's the content of the $html variable at that point?

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOM parser,see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php for more informations.

Comment: after trying a bunch of different ways, i get  Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/a8615089/public_html/evpluginfinder/findshit.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to 1)grab the websites or 2)how to strip the data.

For 1) Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpQuery to parse that page and get the contents you want

[PhpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics)